# Laravel and vue.js, failed to call api in vue.js and laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

im tring to get user data from my laravel with vue js, however i trying its always fail

here my laravel code in api.php route folder:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user();
});
```

and here is my vue js code :

```
export default {
props: ['product', 'authenticatedUser'],

methods: {
getUser () {
  this.$http.get('api/user/')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
   }
  }
}
```

my code work for another case, but if i trying to get user data by click a button its fails, here is my error

```
Failed to load http://localhost/hadirr/laracore/public/api/products/: 
Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
feed#:1 Uncaught (in promise) Response {url: 
"http://localhost/hadirr/laracore/public/api/products/", ok: false, status: 
0, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}
```

here is my complete error message :

[image: yea i have authenticated]

Comment: ```http://localhost/hadirr/laracore/public/api/products/``` does not look like the url you are calling via ajax. Does this url exist?

Comment: sorry the righ url is http://localhost/hadirr/laracore/public/api/user/ i have changed it but result still same. still got this error Failed to load http://localhost/hadirr/laracore/public/api/user/: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Comment: Is the api called after the user logged in? Look at the browser console, where it redirected. If it redirected to login url, maybe thats the issue.

Comment: also see the response body in the console if it's something like 404 then the route doesn't exist, otherwise put it here

Comment: @DharmaSaputra i have authenticated, in another case 'api/user/' work, and when i try call the route in browser url is exis and give back some array, so i think the route is fine, but i fail to call it in spesific vue file.

Comment: @Hussein ""
bodyText
:
""
headers
:
Headers
map
:
""
:
Array(1)
0
:
""
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
ok
:
false
status
:
0
statusText
:
""
url
:
"http://localhost/hadirr/laracore/public/api/user/"
data
:
(...) my status is 0

Comment: maybe you need to handle the cors, that is if any request from vue is not working: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: also it seems that it's redirecting, check the Controller for `api/user`

Comment: thanks hussein, the problem is my cors just handle post method, when i change it to *, its working